# Error installing tensorflow with pip, no module named 'termcolor'

Tags: python, tensorflow, termcolor

Im trying to install tensorflow, using pip install tensorflow. I can install other packages but tensorflow is just not working. This is the error i get:

> `C:\Users\sebas>python -m pip install tensorflow`

> `Collecting tensorflow` 
> `Using cached tensorflow-2.8.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (437.9 MB)` 
> `Collecting h5py>=2.9.0`  
> `Using cached h5py-3.6.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (2.8 MB)` 
> `Collecting tensorboard<2.9,>=2.8` 
> `Using cached tensorboard-2.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (5.8 MB)` 
> `Collecting termcolor>=1.1.0` 
> `Using cached termcolor-1.1.0.tar.gz (3.9 kB)` 
> `Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error` 
> `error: subprocess-exited-with-error` 
> `× python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.` 
> `│ exit code: 1` 
> `╰─> [6 lines of output]` 
> `Traceback (most recent call last):` 
> `File "<string", line 36, in <module>` 
> `File "pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>` 
> `File "C:\Users\sebas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vmfvacm3 \termcolor_be9b831904ce413daecad52b36f017aa\setup.py", line 35, in <module>` 
> `from termcolor import VERSION` 
> `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'termcolor'` 
> `[end of output]`  
> `note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.` 
> `error: metadata-generation-failed` 
> `× Encountered error while generating package metadata.` 
> `╰─> See above for output.`  
> `note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.` 
> `hint: See above for details.` \

Comment: did you try to install first `termcolor` ? Maybe it will show more information.

Comment: Yes it gives me the same error and when i try to install tensorflow.

Comment: so main problem is `termcolor` and you need to find out why it can't install it. `pip` has option `--verbose` which may display more information when you install `termcolor`. Maybe it needs some C/C++ library which you would have to install separatelly (not with `pip`).

Comment: I checked file `setup.py` in package `termcolor` and it looks like it try to load termcolor to get `VERSION` before it is installed. The older version 0.2 doesn't do this. Maybe first install older version `pip install termcolor==0.2` and later update to newer `pip install -U termcolor`

Comment: You may also download `termcolor` as file .`whl` from [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) and try to install `pip install termcolor‑1.1.0‑py2.py3‑none‑any.whl`

Comment: Downloading and installing the whl file worked! Thank you very much! You just saved me a lot of stress.

Comment: so I add this as answer - maybe it will help someone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For people which will have similiar problem (on Windows)

---

Main problem is `termcolor`.

It seems it tries to import `VERSION` from new version (before instalation) but it behaves like it would load older versions which doesn't have `VERSION`.

You may download `termcolor` as file `.whl` from

[Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/)

and try to install

```
pip install termcolor‑1.1.0‑py2.py3‑none‑any.whl
```

Answer (score 0):

If termcolor‑1.1.0‑py2.py3‑none‑any.whl can no longer be found on [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/) you may find it here [termcolor-whl · PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/termcolor-whl/#files)